# Cold upper interior and exterior walls, moisture forms when showering

Tags: drywall

The house is 3 years old. Exterior walls have bat insulation. The interior walls have no insulation. One interior wall in the top corner where it meets the exterior wall, particularly is very cold.

When someone showers the upper part of the wall show moisture, wet spots all around half the bathroom. The visible moisture areas will go away after an hour or two.

One wall has plumbing.

Above the bathroom is the attic with blown in insulation.
House is 1 story on a slab.

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need a good exhaust fan to keep the moisture down.

Good luck!

Comment: +1 - Also, make sure it's vented all the way outside, not just into the attic.